# How to protect code in snaps from unauthorised access?

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-core, snap

I have observed that once a snap is install all the code is accessible in the /snap/snap_package/current directory. Is there a way of preventing access to this code by unauthorised users?

Comment: Who's an unauthorised user? What's the harm in them reading it?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I'm new to this. I am using a raspberry pi for my IoT product and I am currently using Raspbian OS and wish to migrate to Snappy.  I just don't want any third party to get his/her hands on the code on the device.

Answer (score 1):

While part of the process of turning it into a snap means all of those files are owned as root, you can still use file mode bits. Take this `snapcraft.yaml` for example:

```
name: not-protected-snap
version: '0.1'
summary: my summary
description: my description

grade: devel
confinement: strict

apps:
  hello:
    command: hello.sh

parts:
  my-part:
    plugin: nil
    build: |
      echo "#!/bin/sh" > $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/hello.sh
      echo "echo \"hello world\"" >> $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/hello.sh
      chmod a+x $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/hello.sh
```

Run `snapcraft` on that, and then `sudo snap install --dangerous <snap>`. This is world readable, as you noted:

```
$ not-protected-snap.hello
hello world
$ cat /snap/not-protected-snap/current/hello.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world"
```

Note what happens if we change this `snapcraft.yaml` a bit:

```
name: protected-snap
version: '0.1'
summary: my summary
description: my description

grade: devel
confinement: strict

apps:
  hello:
    command: hello.sh

parts:
  my-part:
    plugin: nil
    build: |
      echo "#!/bin/sh" > $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/hello.sh
      echo "echo \"hello world\"" >> $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/hello.sh
      chmod 500 $SNAPCRAFT_PART_INSTALL/hello.sh
```

Run `snapcraft` on that, and then `sudo snap install --dangerous <snap>`. Now you'll see the differences you'd expect:

```
$ protected-snap.hello 
/snap/protected-snap/x1/command-hello.wrapper: 5: exec: /snap/protected-snap/x1/hello.sh: Permission denied
$ cat /snap/protected-snap/current/hello.sh cat: /snap/protected-snap/current/hello.sh: Permission denied
$ sudo protected-snap.hello
hello world
$ sudo cat /snap/protected-snap/current/hello.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo "hello world"
```